# Update specific number of rows based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If I want to updated only a specific number of records based on a filter in a Pandas data frame what should I do?

In this case I am filtering all 'Tickets' series equals to 10 and I want to increment in one the first 5. Here's my attempt:

```
df.loc[df['Tickets'] == 10, 'Tickets'].iloc[:5] += 1
```

If I remove .iloc[:5] this call works pretty fine, but not like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain of `.loc` and `.iloc` may cause the unsung error , so you may can check

```
df.update(df.loc[df['Tickets'] == 10, ['Tickets']].iloc[:5]+1)
```

Comment: @brenoriba yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Here I think you are updating a copy of the dataframe, you may do :

```py
df.loc[np.where(df['Tickets'] == 10)[0][:5], 'Tickets'] += 1
```